# How can I make a left join in a temporal query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have the following table:

```
char, id_1, id_2
a,100,50
a,100,50
a,100,50
b,101,50
b,101,50
c,200,51
c,200,51
d,201,51
e,202,52
e,202,52
e,202,52
e,202,52
```

I want to produce this output:

```
id_1, id_2, count, sum
100,50,3,5
101,50,2,5
200,51,2,3
201,51,1,3
202,52,4,4
```

A short explication:

I want to count the number of rows given the "id_1" and produce the column "count"
then once I have the "count" column, I want to create the "sum" column by summing the groups
of the id_2

I first try this:

```
select id_1, id_2, count(id_2) as count from myTable
group by id_1, id_2
```

to make the count column,

```
id_1, id_2, count
100,50,3
101,50,2
200,51,2
201,51,1
202,52,4
```

the problem is that I can't make the sum column.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySql 8+ then *window functions* make this relatively simple:

```
select id_1, id_2, Count(*) "Count", Max(cnt) "sum"
from (
    select *, Count(*) over(partition by id_2) cnt
    from t
)t
group by id_1, id_2;
```

[See demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88514885410ffff4e4b8c652f1f1abdd)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is actually the thing that I wanted :D

Answer (score 0):

As Stu put it, window functions make this task a breeze. Here's my take on this task (By the time I finished Stu had already replied, might as well share mine anyway).

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  `id_1` INTEGER,
  `id_2` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Test
  (`id_1`, `id_2`)
VALUES
  ('100', '50'),
  ('100', '50'),
  ('100', '50'),
  ('101', '50'),
  ('101', '50'),
  ('200', '51'),
  ('200', '51'),
  ('201', '51'),
  ('202', '52'),
  ('202', '52'),
  ('202', '52'),
  ('202', '52');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select distinct 
*,
count(id_1) over (partition by id_1) as count,
count(id_2) over (partition by id_2) as sum
from Test;
```

| id_1 | id_2 | count | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 50 | 3 | 5 |
| 101 | 50 | 2 | 5 |
| 200 | 51 | 2 | 3 |
| 201 | 51 | 1 | 3 |
| 202 | 52 | 4 | 4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: thank you very much for your help, that's exactly the thing that I need, and, if I want to make a new column call "freq" dividing the count/sum but I have this error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'count' in 'field list'

select distinct 
*,
count(id_1) over (partition by id_1) as count,
count(id_2) over (partition by id_2) as sum
count/sum as IDX
from Test;

Comment: Your method here doesn't work because the count and sum columns don't exist at this stage. You can only refer to columns that exist in the FROM statement, whether that's a table or a query.

Comment: How about this? select distinct 
*,
count(id_1) over (partition by id_1) as count,
count(id_2) over (partition by id_2) as sum,
count(id_1) over (partition by id_1)/count(id_2) over (partition by id_2) as idx
from Test;